# Phonegap getCurrentPosition and watchPosition

Tags: cordova

I read so many post about this.
I didn't find a solution.
What i need is to update my current position. So if i will keep moving, i need to know (each 5 seconds) my new position. I understand that watchPosition doesn't work with IOS.

i'm starting from official example and i mix with setInterval

```
// Wait for PhoneGap to load
        //
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        // PhoneGap is ready
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
            setInterval(navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError),5000);
        }

        // onSuccess Geolocation
        //
        function onSuccess(position) {
            alert("ENTRY");
            var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
            element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '           + position.coords.latitude              + '<br />' +
            'Longitude: '          + position.coords.longitude             + '<br />' +
            'Altitude: '           + position.coords.altitude              + '<br />' +
            'Accuracy: '           + position.coords.accuracy              + '<br />' +
            'Altitude Accuracy: '  + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy      + '<br />' +
            'Heading: '            + position.coords.heading               + '<br />' +
            'Speed: '              + position.coords.speed                 + '<br />' +
            'Timestamp: '          + new Date(position.timestamp)          + '<br />';
        }

        // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
        //
        function onError(error) {
            alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
                  'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
        }
```

The result is that i see just one times all information. And then stopping. 
Could someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

watchPosition works fine for me on iOS using latest Cordova (Phonegap). Maybe you should give that method another try, as it seems like it's exactly what you want.

Comment: Perhaps @user1301094 was confused because it doesn't work in the simulator.

Comment: No, i'm using it in my iPad, not in the simulator! Is it possible that the reasons is because i'm using Phongeap 1.2.0?

Comment: Could be. I had trouble as well (GPS would not shut down) using an earlier Phonegap version. It magically disappeared when I updated to the first Cordova version.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue, watchposition call backs are not firing regardless of web app or not on IOS6. It appears IOS6 has broken the watchPosition. on start it fires once or twice and that's it. once failed out further calls of the watch or getposition do not fire success or failure callbacks.

the work around I am finding is to open the maps app that was introduced in IOS 6 and tap the location arrow to find yourself. after trying this the callbacks fire as expected every second or so.

Also, it appears to stay running well as long as you are outside where the GPS receiver is being used.

I submitted as bug to apple.

All I can gather is maps is performing an initialize routine to open the API...

WatchPosition has worked perfectly until IOS6.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you are passing a *value* to setInterval instead of a *function*.  You should have something more like this:

```
setInterval( function(){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
},
5000);
```

As you have it now, getCurrentPosition runs once, returns the position to the setInterval function... and then the position *value* is called every 5 seconds (not the getCurrentPosition *function*), which is pretty meaningless.