# getCurrentPosition almost always failing in PhoneGap 1.3 on iOS 6

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, geolocation

I have an existing PhoneGap 1.3 app that does some geolocation that works just fine in iOS 4 and 5. In iOS 6, getCurrentPosition almost always fires the failure callback. After a failure, additional getCurrentPosition calls do not fire either the success or failure callbacks. I've reduced the app down to the following code, which exhibits the same behavior as my full app.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
  console.log('deviceready!!!');
  successCallback = function() {
    console.log('success!!!');
  };
  failureCallback = function() {
    console.log('failure!!!');
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function() { console.log('success 2'); }, function() { console.log('failure 2'); });
  };
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, failureCallback);
}, false);
```

When it fails, this is what I get in the log:

```
2012-09-24 16:26:46.576 MyAppName[7250:16703] [INFO] deviceready!!!
2012-09-24 16:26:56.582 MyAppName[7250:16703] [INFO] failure!!!
```

Nothing more.

Any ideas on where to go with this?

Comment: iOS6 may have a problem with the geolocalisation getCurrentPosition. Have you tried Apache Cordova ? It may help you to get it work. (see similar thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412239/phonegap-getcurrentposition-and-watchposition)

Comment: There are many known bugs. You definitly should update to cordova 2.1

Answer (score 0):

The answer: Set EnableLocation in PhoneGap.plist to NO. Apparently, having it set to YES causes PhoneGap apps running in iOS 6 to have memory problems. A fix has been implemented, but as of right now, I don't think it's in the official PhoneGap release. FWIW, I can't find anyone who actually knows what EnableLocation does.